# In Soy (Closure) templates, how can I print an expression that might be undefined at runtime?

Tags: google-closure-templates

Let's say the template model contains a map called `$myMap` whose keys are unknown at compile time. If my template attempts to print a map entry using `{$myMap[$someValidKey]}`, all is fine. However if I try to print using `{$myMap[$someInvalidKey]}`, the template fails to render and instead throws this error:

`In 'print' tag, expression "$myMap[$someInvalidKey]" evaluates to undefined.`

How can I tell the template to simply print nothing if that expression is undefined, i.e. no such key exists in the map?

Comment: I've worked around this by ensuring the map contains an entry for all possible keys, but that's obviously not ideal.

Comment: Can you wrap it? `{if $myMap[$someInvalidKey]}{$myMap[$someInvalidKey]}{/if}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just verified that you can conditionally wrap it:

`{if $myMap[$someInvalidKey]}{$myMap[$someInvalidKey]}{/if}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{$myMap[$someInvalidKey] ?: ''}` to fall back to printing nothing (empty string) in the case that it's undefined.